# Angular - HttpClient and interceptors communication

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I want to active/disable a behavior in http client interceptor based on different scenarios in my system. I want to easily enable/disable a secureRequest. A secure request should make sure that the user is authenticated (if the token exist) before the request and make sure the response doesn't throw an Unauthorized Error. When request failed using secure request, user will be navigated to login page. I thought about sending the request with an header. this header will be used only for the interceptor and will be removed by him. I know it can work but it feels very wrong.

Comment: It will probably be possible without hacking the headers soon: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18155

Comment: just use a public variable "isSecure" in the interceptor. if (!isSecure)
      return next.handle(req);